# When starting WAS 8.5 app server from a docker container getting 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, ibm-was, ibm-cloud-plugin

I have a docker image that install the WAS 8.5 (Developer Edition) with fix packs.

Now I create and start my Docker Container (was8cont) exposing few public ports.

Now when I start the App Server using command --

`docker exec was8cont /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/startServer.sh server1`

I'm getting error as

```
Error response from daemon: 
    502 Bad Gateway -- nginx
```

I have the container memory as 2GB.

My Docker File is:

```
From ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Nandakumar Kuthalaraja <n.kuthalaraja@perficient.com>
RUN apt-get install -y unzip 
################ Installation manager ##############
#Install Installation Manager
COPY agent.installer.linux.gtk.x86_64_1.8.3000.20150606_0047.zip /tmp/
RUN mkdir /tmp/im && unzip -qd /tmp/im /tmp/agent*.zip \
 && /tmp/im/installc -acceptLicense -accessRights admin \
 -installationDirectory "/opt/IBM/InstallationManager" \
 -dataLocation "/var/ibm/InstallationManager" -showProgress \
 && rm -fr /tmp/agent*.zip /tmp/im
#Install IBM WAS v8 --com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v85
COPY WAS_V8_1_OF_3.zip /tmp/
COPY WAS_V8_2_OF_3.zip /tmp/
COPY WAS_V8_3_OF_3.zip /tmp/
RUN mkdir /tmp/was && unzip -qd /tmp/was /tmp/WAS_V8_1_OF_3.zip \
 && unzip -qd /tmp/was /tmp/WAS_V8_2_OF_3.zip \
 && unzip -qd /tmp/was /tmp/WAS_V8_3_OF_3.zip \
 && /opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl -showProgress \
 -acceptLicense install com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85 \
 -repositories /tmp/was/repository.config \
 -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer \
 && rm -fr /tmp/was /tmp/WAS_V8_1_OF_3.zip \
  /tmp/WAS_V8_2_OF_3.zip    /tmp/WAS_V8_3_OF_3.zip
# Install fixpack
COPY 8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP0000005-part1.zip /tmp/
COPY 8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP0000005-part2.zip /tmp/
RUN mkdir /tmp/wasfp \
&& unzip -qd /tmp/wasfp /tmp/8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP0000005-part1.zip \
&& rm -fr /tmp/8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP0000005-part1.zip \
&& unzip -qd /tmp/wasfp /tmp/8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP0000005-part2.zip \
&& rm -fr /tmp/8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP0000005-part2.zip \
&& /opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl -showProgress \
-acceptLicense install com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85  \
-repositories /tmp/wasfp/repository.config \
-installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer \
&& rm -fr /tmp/wasfp
# Create AppServer Profile
RUN /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/manageprofiles.sh -create -templatePath /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/default/ -profileName AppSrv01 -profilePath /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01
EXPOSE 2809 9402 9403 9353 9633 9100 11004 11003 9401 7276 7286 5558 5578 5060 5061 9943 9080 9043 9060 8880
```

Comment: Could you please provide us more details, like your Dockerfile for instance? I am not sure why you added the Bluemix tag. Is this related to Bluemix?

Comment: yes actually I'm deploying the docker image in bluemix and starting my container there.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to take a look at the Dockerfiles for WAS classic that we have recently made available: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-classic

You'll see in this example that we start the server as part of the command executed when the container is run rather than having to use a separate exec. You should also get a considerably smaller image if you follow these steps.