# Traditional Websphere docker - copy XML to node

Tags: java, docker, websphere, websphere-8

I'm attempting to dockerize an older application.  Part of this work involves importing the namespace bindings, resources, security, and variables (XML files) in to the Docker container.

Issue I'm encountering is with the COPY command:

```
COPY --chown=was:root resources/xml/ /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/DefaultCell01/nodes/DefaultNode01
```

With this command in place, the Websphere server crashes and Docker container exits.

Full DockerFile:

```
FROM ibmcom/websphere-traditional:8.5.5.17

ENV ENABLE_BASIC_LOGGING=true

COPY tWAS/PASSWORD /tmp/PASSWORD
COPY resources/db2/ /opt/IBM/db2drivers/

COPY --chown=was:root resources/xml/ /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/DefaultCell01/nodes/DefaultNode01
COPY --chown=was:root application.ear /work/app/Application.ear
COPY --chown=was:root tWAS/1_app_deploy.py /work/config/

RUN /work/configure.sh
```

I'm partially guessing that the directory I'm attempting to copy isn't available at server start (can't confirm when/if the directories are generated) or is a permissions issue.  Unfortunately it crashes quickly with the following error:

```
Starting server ...................
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
         /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server1/startServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error:
         com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
ADMU1211I: To obtain a full trace of the failure, use the -trace option.
ADMU0211I: Error details may be seen in the file:
         /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/server1/startServer.log
```

I'm aware of an option to create new namespace bindings using wsadmin scripts (which would be a large amount of work), but no alternatives for the other XML configurations.

Update:
Using `docker run bash` as suggested by lwestby, I was able to retrieve the startServer.log:

```
[8/25/20 2:41:59:744 UTC] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[8/25/20 2:41:59:843 UTC] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
[8/25/20 2:41:59:848 UTC] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
[8/25/20 2:41:59:866 UTC] 00000001 ImplFactory   W   WSVR0072W: Ignoring undeclared override of interface, com.ibm.websphere.cluster.topography.DescriptionManager, with implementation, com.ibm.ws.cluster.propagation.bulletinboard.BBDescriptionManager
[8/25/20 2:41:59:966 UTC] 00000001 SDKUtils      A   ADML0004E: An exception occurred when attempting to expand variable $(JAVA_HOME) com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.variable.UndefinedVariableException: Undefined variable JAVA_HOME
....
[8/25/20 2:42:02:938 UTC] 00000001 DefaultLaunch I   ADML3001W: The defaultEnvironment property is missing from the systemlaunch.properties file.
[8/25/20 2:42:02:939 UTC] 00000001 LaunchCommand A   ADML0004E: An exception occurred when attempting to expand variable ${USER_INSTALL_ROOT} com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.variable.UndefinedVariableException: Undefined variable USER_INSTALL_ROOT
```

Comment: If you `docker run ... bash` the intermediate image just before it runs configure.sh, can you get to some of the log files and see if it provides a more detailed error?

Comment: Unfortunately, according to another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34912109/1742597), the server starts as part of the container run so I don't *think* I can pause execution to get the logs.

Comment: If you run it with the bash command (`docker run -it ibmcom/websphere-traditional bash`), that'll overwrite the CMD directive for the image and let you start the server manually. It'll also let it crash/stop without taking the container with it..

Comment: After using the above command, I was able to retrieve startServer.log after copying the XML files.  Have updated the question with log snippet.

Comment: It appears that several variables are missing (LOG_ROOT, WAS_INSTALL_ROOT, JAVA_HOME) from a system properties file?

Comment: Compared the default variables.xml with the one that was supplied by the legacy apps install instructions. It was missing the majority of entries. Server can now start after copying XML files!